# How to override Python list(iterator) behaviour?

Tags: python

Running this:

```
class DontList(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print 'Getting item %s' % key
        if key == 10: raise KeyError("You get the idea.")
        return None

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print 'Getting attr %s' % name
        return None

list(DontList())
```

Produces this:

```
Getting attr __length_hint__
Getting item 0
Getting item 1
Getting item 2
Getting item 3
Getting item 4
Getting item 5
Getting item 6
Getting item 7
Getting item 8
Getting item 9
Getting item 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list.py", line 11, in <module>
    list(DontList())
  File "list.py", line 4, in __getitem__
    if key == 10: raise KeyError("You get the idea.")
KeyError: 'You get the idea.'
```

How can I change that so that I'll get `[]`, while still allowing access to those keys `[1]` etc.?

(I've tried putting in `def __length_hint__(self): return 0`, but it doesn't help.)

**My real use case:** (for perusal if it'll be useful; feel free to ignore past this point)

After applying [a certain patch](http://code.google.com/p/iniparse/issues/detail?id=25) to iniparse, I've found a nasty side-effect to my patch. Having `__getattr__` set on my `Undefined` class, which returns a new `Undefined` object. Unfortunately, this means that `list(iniconfig.invalid_section)` (where `isinstance(iniconfig, iniparse.INIConfig)`) is doing this (put in simple `print`s in the `__getattr__` and `__getitem__`):

```
Getting attr __length_hint__
Getting item 0
Getting item 1
Getting item 2
Getting item 3
Getting item 4
```

Et cetera ad infinitum.

Comment: Note that some of these answers ignore certain aspects of list(x) -- it will first call  __iter__ and then __len__ on that if that exists and then will run through the iterator.  Make sure that if __len__ has any side effects (on one of my objects it needs to run through the iterator itself to know how many elements it has) that it is reset when it is done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to override the iteration then just define the `__iter__` method in your class

Comment: I thought very vaguely about that at one point but didn't end up trying it as it wasn't showing `Getting attr __iter__`; apparently `hasattr` or whatever it uses doesn't do it that way. What would you recommend then to produce `[]` - `def __iter__(self): return iter([])` (it works but is it the proper way)? Or perhaps I want the usual `TypeError: 'Undefined' object is not iterable` - is there some way I could get it that way (without cheating by producing that error myself)?

Comment: Well iter usually pops the store of the next item, hence why generators are hard to go backwards to the previous state. You could always have def __iter__(self): raise TypeError

Comment: After thinking this and Sven's answer over, I think I want to override `__iter__` with `return; yield` rather than raising `IndexError` on `int` in `__getitem__`, to make the `Undefined` INI section behave like a defined section - things like `for section in iniconfig`, `for key in section`, `if section in iniconfig` and `if key in section` should work as well.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: Don't understand what you mean by `def __iter__(self): return; yield`. An `__iter__()` method needs to `return` something other than `None`, and following that with a `yield` or any other statement would do nothing. Perhaps you should submit your own answer or update your question to show the code you're talking about.

Comment: @martineau: The use of `yield` (in unreachable code but that doesn't matter) there makes it return a generator.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: Oh, OK, that's clever. However the `return` (of `None` implicitly) makes it not iterate at all, not even partially.

Comment: @martineau: that's the idea - `return` is equivalent to `raise StopIteration()` in a generator, meaning it'll produce essentially `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Just raise `IndexError` instead of `KeyError`.  `KeyError` is meant for mapping-like classes (e.g. `dict`), while `IndexError` is meant for sequences.

If you define the [`__getitem__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method on your class, Python will automatically generate an iterator from it.  And the iterator terminates upon `IndexError` -- see [PEP234](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but the problem is that "1" is a perfectly valid INI section or value name. But perhaps I can make it raise IndexError for `1` and accept `'1'`. I think `def __iter__(self): return; yield` is neater though.

Answer (score 3):

As [@Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256357/how-to-override-python-listiterator-behaviour/4256673#4256673) says, that's the wrong error to raise. But that's not the point, the point is that this is broken because it's *not something you should do*: preventing `__getattr__` from raising `AttributeError` means that you have overridden Python's default methodology for testing whether an object has an attribute and replaced it with a new one (`ini_defined(foo.bar)`).

But Python already has [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr)! Why not use that?

```
>>> class Foo:
...     bar = None
...
>>> hasattr(Foo, "bar")
True
>>> hasattr(Foo, "baz")
False
```

Comment: +1. I usually don't upvote "don't do that" answers, but this is one of those cases where Python doesn't make it obvious that you shouldn't do this, and yet it never seems to work out too well in practice. My gut instinct is, don't do that.

Comment: I think this API change would break any existing code that uses `hasattr` to test whether a key exists in an undefined section.

Comment: The reason it needs to be done with the Undefined object is so that you can set INI values without needing to explicitly create the section. That's the design of iniparse and that's correct. `ini_defined` is just a simple function I wrote so that I could check if a section or value *was* defined. `'bar' in foo` should also work (really, that's neater, but it's broken on Undefined the same way this list() business is) - I think I'll change all usage of `ini_defined(foo.bar)` to `'bar' in foo`.

Comment: @Chris: that's almost certainly a bad design, although I understand you may not wish to change it. `'bar' in foo` is much better, because you can override `__getitem__` which is valid in this case.

Comment: I don't believe it is bad design - except for my use of `ini_defined`. I'm not sure why it didn't occur to me to use `x in y` before; it's always worked just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Override how your class is iterated by implementing an `__iter__()` method. Iterator signal when they're finished by raising a `StopIteration` exception, which is part of the normal iterator protocol and not propagated further. Here's one way of applying that to your example class:

```
class DontList(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print 'Getting item %s' % key
        if key == 10: raise KeyError("You get the idea.")
        return None

    def __iter__(self):
        class iterator(object):
            def __init__(self, obj):
                self.obj = obj
                self.index = -1
            def __iter__(self):
                return self
            def next(self):
                if self.index < 9:
                    self.index += 1
                    return self.obj[self.index]
                else:
                    raise StopIteration

        return iterator(self)

list(DontList())
print 'done'
# Getting item 0
# Getting item 1
# ...
# Getting item 8
# Getting item 9
# done
```

Comment: i think that's an overkill...if you want to do that (and the OP don't) just raise StopIteration instead of KeyError in __getitem_

Comment: @Ant: Perhaps. I wrote out a full-blown version because I wasn't sure whether the OP wanted to stop at 10 or skip it. Making the iterator an separate object makes it much more general...and flexible.

Comment: No, that was just demonstrative of the problem that it doesn't stop. Actually, `def __iter__(self): return; yield` works quite nicely.

Comment: +1 for the intuitive example. It is not meant to be used directly, however. You have to nested "overloaded iterators", and in my problem I just needed a single class - just returning an appropriate generator from the `__iter__(self)` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `return iter([])` is the right way, but let's start thinking how `list()` works:

Get an element from `__iter__`; if receive a `StopIrteration` error stops..then get that element..

So you have just to `yield` an empty generator in `__iter__`,  for example `(x for x in xrange(0, 0))`, or simply `iter([]))`

Comment: `iter([])` works, but is overly hacky. `return; yield` is also slightly hacky in the way it abuses yield but neater.