# use "in" operator for dictionary in a class

Tags: python

I have a __contains__ method in class called "Graph" with an instance "dict" which is a dictionary.

```
def __contains__(self,i):
    return i in self.dict
```

Now I would like to use "in" to loop through the keys of "dict." I use:

```
g = Graph()
for i in g:
    print(i)
```

The question is: why I get **values** of dict instead of **keys** from *i*?

Comment: Do you have the code for the `Graph` class?

Answer (score 2):

`__contains__` is not used when iterating. `in` the operator is not the same thing as the [`for ... in ...` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) (even though it contains the word `in`).

Iteration either uses [`object.__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) (passing in integers starting at `0` until an `IndexError` is raised), or uses the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) via the [`object.__iter__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#container.__iter__).

You probably have a `__getitem__` or `__iter__` method that produces values rather than keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the python

```
__iter__
```

method.

```
def __iter__(self):
  for x in self.dict.keys():
     yield x
```

[How to override Python list(iterator) behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256357/how-to-override-python-listiterator-behaviour)

Comment: Thank you! I know what is the problem now.